# Order of excecution, static blocks, fields

Tags: java, static, block

I know that static blocks are run before anything. But here, what happens when B.test() is called? Order of execution and setting of values? Later, when b1 is set to null, still how b1.i evaluates to 20?

```
class  B
{    
     static int i;
     static {
         i = 20;
         System.out.println("SIB");
     }
     static int test() {  
         int i = 24;
         System.out.println(i);
         return i; 
     }
}

public class Manager {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
         B.test();
         B b1 = null;
         System.out.println(b1.i);  
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
SIB
24
20
```

Comment: B.test didn't set any static or instance variables, so calling it would have no long-term effect.  (Read it VERY carefully.)

Comment: Btw, it's a bad practice to access a static member from a non-static reference (such as b1 instance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is static, so `b1.i` is equivalent to `B.i`.  Just setting `b1` to `null` doesn't change any static variables.

When `B.test()` is called, first the `B` class is loaded, and the static blocks are run.  Next, `B.test()` creates a new method-local variable called `i`, which is completely different from `B.i`.  This new, local `i` is printed and returned.  No changes are made to `B.i`, and *certainly* not just because you created a new `B` object reference that was null -- that would never have any effect on anything.

Comment: Thanks, but when b1 is set to null, it should store, point to nothing. Shouldn't b1.i give nullPointerException, since b1 refers to nothing, it won't refer to inside values like i or other fields?

Comment: Referencing static fields as if they were instance variables is kind of funny, but basically, if you reference `instance.staticField`, it'll totally ignore the value of `instance` -- even if it's null.

Answer (score 5):

The value of `i` here

```
static int i;
static {
    i = 20;
    System.out.println("SIB");
}
```

is set to 20 and never modified, so when you access `b1.i`, it's still `20`.

In your `test()` method you are using another `i` variable that is not related to the static one.

Answer (score 1):

> But here, what happens when B.test() is called? Order of execution and setting of values?

There is no change.

> Later, when b1 is set to null, still how b1.i evaluates to 20?

Because `b1` isn't used, the field is static so you are actually using `B.i`

Answer (score 1):

What happens is:

- `B.test()` is called for the first time, before actually running it:
- Class `B` is loaded,
- Static initializer executed (`B.i = 20` now)
- Contents of `B.test()` method are executed
- (creates a method-local `int i = 24` (which shadows the static variable `B.i`) and prints it)
- `b1.i` is interpreted as `B.i` (which is still `20`) and it's printed.

Comment: Thanks, but when b1 is set to null, it should store, point to nothing. Shouldn't b1.i give nullPointerException, since b1 refers to nothing, it won't refer to inside values like i or other fields? b1.i --> null.i ?

Comment: No, you're accessing a static variable, which is stored in the class, not in the instance. The compiler actually just looks at the class of `b1` and figures out that you are accessing `B.i`. It never tries to do anything with the instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
What you did:             What really happened:
B.test()                  - static block of class B is run, static i set to 20, SIB is displayed
                          - test method is called, local property i set to 24, 24 is displayed
b1 = null                 - set reference for b1 to null. Note that this doesn't change the value of class B's static properties
System.out.println(b1.i)  - b1 is still Class B. It doesn't matter what its current reference is. Static i for class B is still 20, 20 is displayed
```